How to create installer for ASP.NET core Razor Pages web application?
I have ASP.NET Web forms web applications and I am using Web setup project to create MSI for web application installation on IIS. MSI is creating folders, coping files, setting permissions,  setting up IIS and web application is done completely and ready to run.
Now I moved to ASP.NET Core and cannot find any kind of Web setup project for that. The only way everywhere I found is to publish manually: create publishing folder by VS, create a folder in IIS, install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle on the IIS, create a web application in IIS, copy files to IIS's folder. Is there a way to make a kind of MSI that will do all those  manual works?

You can write a script for that
https://tecadmin.net/create-website-and-apppool-in-iis-using-appcmd/

From the developer standpoint you only need to know that you must build the project using dotnet publish ..... command. Everything else here is for admin/super user/dev ops. You can use INNO install, its free. Dev ops, or whoever, must prepare the site and then copy your code. You can provide instruction how to setup. This is unreasonable to expect that your installer will do all the administrative tasks.

See if this can meet your needs https://wixtoolset.org/

@T.S., scripting looks like more administrative work for admins not for me. My developer standpoint the last 20 years was not only creating app but MSI too. So IT people the last 20 year know what to do with MSI. My MSI is doing everything: checking a version of IIS, creating web app in IIS, copying files, creating additional folders and permissions, checking existence of previous versions of web app, preserving configuration files, connecting to services for finishing settings.  I am afraid I'll be fired if I change company rules. Thank you for options but I am not lucky to pick any of them.

"last 20 years ..." a lot of water passed in the river. I do this every day. Our customers take a zip file and we have deployment documentation they use to create environment on their side. And on our side DevOps create Jenkins jobs that run the scripts and not Installs. These days the whole approach of CICD has changed from 20 years back. If you create an app for a user desktop install is a great idea. But if this is a server side deployment, most of the time - an overkill. Unless it is highly configurable and customizable install, like SQL Server DB installation, e.g.

But if you insist on installs - WIX, INNO. Could be others

Could you please share do you want just to overcome the manual deployment process or any other objective later on?

@MdFaridUddinKiron, I want just to overcome the manual deployment process.

I got you. Thanks for your response.
